# Return an .NET object reference from a Windows Service when I can't add [Serializable]

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, com, .net-remoting

I work with external HW from the PC that requires to be booted ( time consuming ). I've been asked to speed this up by writing some software that will boot the hardware and then allow client's to obtain a reference to the hardware. Currently they have to reboot the HW every time they restart their software.

All the HW we use is 3rd party and written c# and therefore I don't have the luxury of being able to modify the hardware classes.

As this all needs to run on the same PC it seems logical that a Windows Service could be used to host some software that would instantiate the hardware class, boot the HW and then return the reference upon request.

**Attempt 1** was a a WCF client hosted in a Windows Service. This worked initially until I realised that WCF is a message based system and does not allow the access to the methods of the returned object...only the data. I eventually realised I was trying to make WCF do something it wasn't intended for. I also couldn't add the DataContract attributes to the 3rd party dll classes.

**Attempt 2** was using .NET Remoting hosted in a Windows Service. This worked initially until I realised I was not going to be able to add the [Serializable] attribute to the 3rd party class(s). I could inherit a class and add the  MarshalByRefObject but this only lets me call the object remotely which will be too slow for our purposes.

I've looked into trying to force WCF to work using shared assemblies and also trying to add an attribute at runtime but both ideas wont fly.

My next attempt is using COM but I thought this shouln't really be this hard....and thought I would consult the SO community to see if I'm just missing something.

To clarify here is an example of the 3rd party class I want to instantiate in the Service and return a copy to the client.

```
    public class afDigitizer : IDigitizerHandle, IDisposable
    {
    public afDigitizerCalibrate Calibrate;
    public afDigitizerCapture Capture;
    public afDigitizerEventOnError EventOnError;
    public afDigitizerEventOnWarning EventOnWarning;
    public afDigitizerListMode ListMode;
    public afDigitizerLO LO;
    public afDigitizerLVDS LVDS;
    public afDigitizerModulation Modulation;
    public afDigitizerRF RF;
    public afDigitizerTimer Timer;
    public afDigitizerTrigger Trigger;

    public afDigitizer();
    public afDigitizer(string installDir);

    ~afDigitizer();

    public int BootInstrument(string LoResource, string RfResource, int LoIsPlugin);}
```

.

```
        // and the code to instantiate the object and boot it.
        private afDigitizer vsa = new afDigitizer();


        errorCode = vsa.BootInstrument(this.LO, this.RF,-1);
        // Now i want to return the vsa object.
```

Comment: Why can't the software get its own reference? What exactly is in the "reference"? Some .NET object? What does that reference object look like? Just because it isn't marked `[Serializable]` doesn't mean it *can't* be serialized...

Comment: "speed this up by writing some software that will boot the hardware and then allow client's to obtain a reference to the hardware."  Can you rephrase this?  I don't understand what this means.  What kind of *reference* to the hardware?  An object reference? To hardware?

Comment: I've added some example code which I hope will clarify the comment from @Ron Beyer.

Comment: The HW reference i refer to is just an instance of a class that talks to the HW. See the example I've added. During development of software that makes use of the instance of the class every time it's disposed the HW is required to be rebooted which is time consuming. The idea is to have a server ( windows service ) instantiate the class and boot the HW and then return a copy of the class ( i think i referred to this as a reference ) to the client software. This works fine for classes that I have complete control over but not for 3rd party classes as per my example.